# Remove line of text from multiple files in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

Is there a simple way to remove the same line of text from a folder full of text documents at the command line?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If your version of sed allows the `-i.bak` flag (edit in place):

```
sed -i.bak '/line of text/d' *
```

If not, simply put it in a bash loop:

```
for file in *.txt
do
    sed '/line of text/d' "$file" > "$file".new_file.txt
done
```

Comment: +1 for the `-i.bak` gsed fu. Your `for loop` probably needs a `mv $file.new_file.txt $file` to match it.

Comment: @Robert, If you miss the right sed, you can still do: `perl -pi.bak -e 's|line of text||g' \*`

Comment: That leaves a blank line rather than deleting the line, right?

Comment: @Ry4an, I guess you are right on that. There is a way to catch the end-of-line along with the text -- but, I can't recall that.

Comment: do I have to use a backslash before any control characters? what are they?

Comment: `$(ls *.txt)` is stupid (forks extra process, can't handle spaces in filenames). try `for file in *.txt` instead

Comment: This failed for me if the folder had subdirectories. `sed -i '/foo/d' *.*` worked.

Comment: This only does a single file in the folder, but not others.

Answer (score 55):

To find `a pattern` and remove `the line containing the pattern` below command can be used

```
find . -name "*" -type f | xargs sed -i -e '/<PATTERN>/d'
```

Example : 
if you want to remove the line containing word `sleep` in all the `xml` files

```
find . -name "*.xml" -type f | xargs sed -i -e '/sleep/d'
```

NOTE : Be careful before choosing a pattern as it will delete the line recursively in all the files in the current directory hierarchy :)

Comment: This doesnt work if the folder path or filename contains spaces.

Comment: Thank you Sitesh.. it saved me from hours of work today.

Answer (score 6):

Consider grep -v:

```
for thefile in *.txt ; do
   grep -v "text to remove" $thefile > $thefile.$$.tmp
   mv $thefile.$$.tmp $thefile
done
```

Grep -v shows all lines except those that match, they go into a temp file, and then the tmpfile is moved back to the old file name.

Answer (score 6):

```
perl -ni -e 'print if not /mystring/' *
```

This tells perl to loop over your file (-n), edit in place (-i), and print the line if it does not match your regular expression.

Somewhat related, here's a handy way to perform a substitution over several files.

```
perl -pi -e 's/something/other/' *
```

Comment: From this [link](http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2009/3/9/191744/8407): both perl and sed are traditional NFA engines, so theoretically they shouldn't differ to greatly in their performance, but in reality perl has a large number of optimisations applied that make it perform well in common cases.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a Perl script for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use IO::Handle;

my $pat = shift(@ARGV) or
    die("Usage: $0 pattern files\n");
die("Usage $0 pattern files\n")
    unless @ARGV;

foreach my $file (@ARGV) {
    my $io = new IO::Handle;
    open($io, $file) or
        die("Cannot read $file: $!\n");
    my @file = <$io>;
    close($io);
    foreach my $line (@file) {
        if($line =~ /$pat/o) {
            $line = '';
            $found = 1;
            last;
        }
    }
    if($found) {
        open($io, ">$file") or
            die("Cannot write $file: $!\n");
        print $io @file;
        close($io);
    }
}
```

Note that it removes lines based on a regex.  If you wanted to do exact match, the inner `foreach` would look like:

```
foreach $line (@file) {
    chomp $line;
    if($line eq $pat) {
        $line = '';
        $found = 1;
        last;
    }
}
```