# Deleting multiple HTML lines in multiple files with Linux commandline

Tags: regex, linux, command-line, html-parsing

I have 1000+ html files, all with more than 1000 lines, on a Linux server.
Most of the files have a particular part of html code that needs to be deleted.

The part that I need to deleted looks about this:

```
<div class="LoginOuterCssClass" id="ctl07">
    ...
</div>
```

Is there some script or command-line solution for this?

Commands like the following didn't help:

```
X,Ys/search/replace/g
1,2s/\([a-z]*\), \([a-z]*\)/\2 \1/ig
s/<[^]*>//g
```

Help would me much appreciated!

Comment: What command did you try for this. In example is some patterns - no real command

Comment: see this question for using *sed* and *grep* to delete one line of text from several files: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1182756/1284631

Comment: What you're talking about is parsing HTML, and simple command line tools are not up to the task.  What if there's a <div> inside of the <div> you want deleted, for example?  What if the closing </div> isn't on a line by itself?  You need a proper HTML parser.

Comment: I used the `find | xargs sed` command, there are 42 lines of HTML and several divs inside de div I want to delete. None of them on the same line. Andy, you talk about a proper HTML parser, what could I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following `sed` command on one file and see if it does what you want:

```
sed -n '/<div class="LoginOuterCssClass" id="ctl07">/{:a;N;/<\/div>/!ba;N;s/.*\n//};p' file.html
```

To run this on multiple files and edit them in-place, you run `find` and pass the files to `sed` via `xargs` as shown below:

```
find /some/path -name "*.html" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -n '/<div class="LoginOuterCssClass" id="ctl07">/{:a;N;/<\/div>/!ba;N;s/.*\n//};p'
```

Comment: I tried `find /some/path -name "*.html" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -in '/<div class="LoginOuterCssClass" id="ctl07">/{:a;N;/<\/div>/!ba;N;s/.*\n//};p'`, it works almost perfectly! Thank you very much! But te content in the file I tested now has every line double. Like `<div class="input">` for example is now `<div class="input">
<div class="input">`. How does this could happen?

Comment: I have fixed the `sed` command. Should have been `-i -n`, not `-in`.

Comment: You just made me very happy! :D Thank you very much!