# Batch delete specific lines of code in 800+ HTML files

Tags: html, excel

I have 800+ HTML files from which I need Code lines 50 - 100 from each file.

I tried Excel macros, terminal and textedit so far but with no luck.

I am looking for an automated solution.

Comment: You need to open the file, extract line 50-100 and repeat that for all 800 files, is that correct?

Comment: Yes,  that could also work

Comment: Ideally store the extracted content all together in one new file below each other

Comment: Can you use powershell ?

Comment: :) Just guessed on windows because of excel macros

Comment: I have office  for mac

Comment: I think i would suggest going with sed then, something like sed -e '50,100d' myfile.html, and then piping the files into sed instead of specifying name as myFile.html

Comment: sed as a command in terminal?

Comment: yes. read more at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83329/how-can-i-extract-a-predetermined-range-of-lines-from-a-text-file-on-unix or even better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182756/remove-line-of-text-from-multiple-files-in-linux

Comment: will try that. thanks for showing

Answer (score 1):

An example of using sed in a shell

oneliner

```
sed -i.bak -e '50,100d' *.html
```

remove lines 50-100 in all files with extension html, save a copy of the original file with a .bak extension.

or in a loop without -i

```
for file in *.html
do
   sed -e '50,100d' "$file" > "$file".bak
done
```

best to take a full backup of all files before playing around with sed. and be . aware that sed is implemented with different options in various versions.